# Reference to check which properties are available for styling a tag?

Tags: css

I am working on styling my `<blockquote>` but I am not able to find a complete reference that would let me check what is available to me (newbie here).

For example, "box-shadow" property. How to check if I can define for `<blockquote>` or not? Trial and error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply ***any*** CSS property to ***any*** HTML element.

Some inline elements don't support properties of block level elements(i.e. padding on `<span>`), but you can easily overcome that restriction by defining them `block` or `inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

Most documentation you'll find is extraordinarily dense and reads like the specifications. As someone who is learning, my best advice to you is to test it out, make the mistakes and learn from them! You'll spend far less time here waiting for an answer you can test yourself in seconds.

That being said, the [Mozilla Developer's Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) has (IMHO) the easiest to absorb documentation around.

P.S. yes, you can use box-shadow on blockquotes

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official list of all properties: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/

I do also like this list: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/css/propindex/all.htm

While there may be some specific attributes that work best with some specific block, the general rule is that you can apply any property to any element. The result may vary from a browser to another.

Please note that some browsers support their own set of properties.